# Select all from one table and if exist take the more details on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two different tables, both there is similar unique keys so I can link both using this ID.

On the first table I have 1287 people registered and on the second table I have just 786 people registered.

Then, I want to show 1287 people of the first table and if exist this same ID on the other table 786 show more information about this subscribed..

I don't know if I could explain very well, but I have no idea how start it.

```
SELECT * FROM oficinas_inscritos, oficina_pesquisa WHERE oficina_pesquisa.cpf = oficinas_inscritos.cpf
```

Comment: Left join says hello?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple LEFT OUTER JOIN:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM oficinas_inscritos
LEFT OUTER JOIN oficina_pesquisa 
ON oficina_pesquisa.cpf = oficinas_inscritos.cpf
```